# Residue along of a curve on $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, residue-calculus

I read the article : Residue of differential on curves of John Tate.

Consider the $ 1 $ -form: $$\omega = (z_{0}^{2} + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})dz_{0} - z_{3}(z_{0}dz_{0} + z_{1}dz_{1} + z_{2}dz_{2}) $$ in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ with singular scheme is: $ C \cup \lbrace [0 : 0 : 0 : 1]$, where: $$C = \lbrace z_{3} = z_{0}^{2} + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2} = 0 \rbrace$$

I don't see how the above article can help me calculate the residue along of  $C$.

My question: In practice, that is, given an example as above, can anyone help me calculate this residue along of $C$ ?

Other references and suggestions will be welcome.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, the article tells you how to compute residues at a closed point  of a curve for a one-form on that curve. What do you mean by "residue along a curve"?

Comment: It is true !! It is set to closed point. Thank you very much, Alan Muniz. I would like to see an explicit example of how you calculate this residue. If the curve is $ C =\mathbb{P}^{1}$,  therefore a Riemann surface, then we have $\displaystyle \sum_{p \in C} \text{Res}(\omega , C) = 0$, right?

Comment: In the example above, I do not know how to calculate such a residue.Do you know how to calculate this residue for this example built in the question?Any help is very welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem in your example is that $\omega$ vanishes along $C$. Then the restriction to $C$ os $0$, every residue is trivially zero. There are several (other) notions of residue that can be applied, measuring, various things. That's why I asked you what do you wanted to calculate.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, Alan Muniz. Taking the opportunity here, what other types of residues be applied and what do they measure? I have a lot of interest in residues. Can you give me references or examples in residues so I can learn more about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: See this paper by Suwa https://www.ems-ph.org/books/show_abstract.php?proj_nr=160&vol=1&rank=12 I find it very readable and interesting. Also, of course, Baum-Bott :)

Comment: Thank you, Alan Muniz.